# How do I create New Registry Key with REG_OPTION_VOLATILE in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, registry, registrykey

Need a Registry key that should not survive reboot.

I referred https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , but that shows C++ implementation.

How do we achieve the same in C#?

Appreciate any responses.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant : Do we have something similar for .Net Framework 3.5?

Comment: Some programmers need an extraordinary amount of assistance to get them to update an ancient 8 year old version of free software.  Not helping them is the only real way to help them.  You can ask for help anyway but properly tagging your question so we can all choose to ignore it is required.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for inputs. Updated Tag. Also, apologies for the use of old framework, but that is not my call to make.